# SUM the current column for many rows, return only one

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with my query.

I tried different ways and searched a lot but I got no luck.

All I want is to `SUM()`, the column `item_price` WHERE `order_id=2`, and show its result along with its other rows.

I've 2 rows under `order_id=2`, so when I try the below query, I get only 1 row.

```
SELECT *, SUM(`item_price`) AS `item_total`
FROM `order_items`
WHERE `order_id` = '2'
```

Ouput

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "order_id": "2",
    "item_name": "Loshan",
    "item_price": "10.000",
    "description": "Don Company Loshan was good",
    "image": "Loshan-1612740664.png",
    "status": "approved",
    "updated_at": "2021-02-08 04:31:04",
    "created_at": "2021-02-08 04:31:04",
    "item_total": "20.000"
}
```

I tried to use `` GROUP BY `id` ``, So I get 2 rows but the result of `item_total` is not valid, it do not sum the whole column where `order_id=2`

I can handle it in **PHP** but I want it to do it with a **SQL** query.

Comment: You might use "Group By" or remove "*, " before the SUM

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: I already tried `GROUP BY`, but then I do not get right output for sum the column. All I need the same output wrote in my question but I need to get other rows where `order_id = 2` as well.